# POSTMAN | GET Variable for if - statement

Tags: postman

i want to do a if statement in Postman. I have the Environmet Variable: server_state1 & server_state2 
These Variables both gets numbers from 0-3. 
Now i want to write a Pre-request-Script in an PUT Statement. 
The IF Statement sounds like

```
var server_state1 = postman.GetEnvironmentVariable("state_server1");
var server_state2 = postman.GetEnvironmentVariable("state_server2");

if (server_state1 === 0 && server_state2 === 0){
   postman.SetEnvironmentVariable("server_state12", "Everything is fine");
}
```

But this does not work.

Comment: What do you mean, when you say it doesn't work? Is the environment variable not being set?

Comment: Yes its not beeing set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

THE ANSWER IS:

```
var server_state1 = postman.GetEnvironmentVariable("state_server1");
var server_state2 = postman.GetEnvironmentVariable("state_server2");

if (server_state1 === "0" && server_state2 === "0"){
postman.SetEnvironmentVariable("server_state12", "Everything is fine");
}
```

Comment: Remember to mark your answer as accepted - and consider editing your answer to include an explanation on what the problem was, and how you fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

The functions you are looking for are defined in lowerCamelCase.

Try to use:

```
postman.getEnvironmentVariable("state_server1")
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("server_state12", "Everything is fine");
```

Instead of:

```
postman.GetEnvironmentVariable("state_server1");
postman.SetEnvironmentVariable("server_state12", "Everything is fine");
```

Comment: Okay thank you for that but the variable still dont set to the environment. :/

Comment: Double check your environment variable names. Is "server_state12" correct?