# How to dynamically set Postman environment variable key

Tags: postman

Hopefully someone can save me!

The environment variable that I want to retrieve will be conditional. For example, sometimes I'll want varA, sometimes varB:

```
let assetA = varA

let assetB = varB
```

Is there a way to retrieve the environment variable using assetA/B?

I tried `pm.environment.get(assetA)` but I get the *unexpected token u* error as it's expecting quotes around the key? Is there a way to pass in a variable instead?

Comment: Did you tried pre-request scripts?

Comment: Unsure what you mean. I do use pre-request scripts but I still have the problem of how to request a variable using a variable :)

Comment: you can either modify the request object itself or update another env variable from pre-req scripts. Say you need to set either `A` or `B` conditionally, so you take another `C` and set it `if COND_A: C = A; else C=B`. Now you can use C inside request.

Comment: I see similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899709/postman-get-variable-for-if-statement

Comment: Sorry I don't think I explained myself well enough...BUT what i tried originally does actually seem to be working after all; i.e. `pm.environment.get(assetA)` will swap out assetA with varA (the key i really want for this condition), and then the value for varA will be the result.

Comment: @simien could you add a real example? as far as I understand, what you want is `pm.environment.get(assetA)` --> `pm.environment.get(varA)` --> value of varA in environment.